# Bash script IDE

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell-script

Is there a bash/ksh/any shell script IDE.

Don't you get annoyed when you forget the space inside if or I don't know, some minor syntax mistakes you do from time to time, but takes you a long time to figure it out(especially when one is tired).

I knew about some suggestion listed below, but I'm looking for something like eclipse(i.e. for java).

Comment: You can use `ShellCheck` to find common bugs and pitfalls in your scripts > http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Powershell has an IDE (they call it an ISE) but not sure if it works on Unix. VSCode seems to be the editor of choice on Linux for powershell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just about every editor support syntax highlighting for shell - this can help you spot problems.

In addition, you can put `set -x` and `set -e` at the top of your scripts. The `-x` tells the shell to print out every command before it executes it. The `-e` tells the shell to terminate the script if any errors occur. These should really help cut down on time spent looking for bugs.

Comment: +1 for showing more forbearance in answering this question than I would. :)